# AngularJS - What's the best way to implement a "picture-in-picture" view within my stated app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm using AngularUI Router within one of my projects which needs to somehow implement a "picture-in-picture" feature... Below is a contrived example:

[image]

In the "List View", you can select one of the items which will bring you to the "Item View" - which has a tiny "List View" embedded there.

So the user can still navigate through the lists in the "List View" to select different items using different listing modes - all the while anything wild can continue to happen inside the "Item View".

Now the interesting part is that since I am using AngularUI Router - which binds the concept of state machine with routing - I am not sure of the best way to approach this issue.

A few possible solutions I've come up so far:

- Make the "List View" into a directive
- Make the "List View" and "Item View" into separate modules with separate state machines and somehow bind them together (I am not sure how to do this)
- Define a dozen few
  more URLless states for the "picture-in-picture List View"

What's the best out of these in your opinion? Or feel free to tell that you've got a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define abstract ListIndex state with ui-view directive to hold child states.
2. Define ListCategory state that is child of ListIndex with resolve object to access category info in your controller List and Item controllers.
3. Define ListCategoryItem state that is child of ListCategory.

Some quick sample code:

```
states.ListIndex = {
   url: '/list',
   abstract: true,
   template: '<div ui-view/>'
};
states.ListCategory = {
  url: '/list/:categoryId',
  controller: ['$scope', 'category', function($scope, category) {
    $scope.category = category;
  }],
  templateUrl: 'category.html',
  resolve: {
    category: ['CategoryService', '$stateParams', function(CategoryService, $stateParams) {
      return CategoryService.get($stateParams.categoryId);
    }]
};
states.ListCategoryItem = {
  url: 'list/:categoryId/:itemId',
  controller: ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
    $scope.item = item;
  }],
  templateUrl: 'item.html',
  resolve: {
    item: ['ItemService', '$stateParams', function(ItemService, $stateParams) {
      return ItemService.get($stateParams.itemId);
    }]
  }
}

//iterate states and add each of them to $stateProvider
//...
```

category template:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in category.items">
   <li>{{item.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

item template:

```
<div item-view="item"></div>

<div ng-include="'category.html'" class="small"></div>
```

Because navigating to ListCategoryItem state preserves category object, you can generate small version of your nav menu in item template without any additional directives.

Comment: Very interesting solution - thanks! But in my case, there are a few more child states for "ListIndex" (it's not a simple listing but kinda like a multi-step chooser), so one of the problems is that when I navigate through the small version of the menu, it will trigger a state change and destroy the "ListCategoryItem" view.

Comment: What is expected to happen with ItemListView when user navigates small menu? Can you elaborate more on ListIndex child states? UI Router's state model fits perfectly for multi-step scenarios, unless there's a requirement for multiple simultaneous states.

Comment: An example that could finely illustrate the condition I am in would be overly complex, and I suspect I did something wrong on the architectural level. Could you enlighten me with a few examples on how to do multi-steps and multiple simultaneous states using AngularUI Router, respectively? I've setup two other separate questions (many thanks!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094671 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094708