# AngularUI Router - What's the best way to implement "multiple simultaneous states"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Say I've got two or more views on the same page that could be seen as widgets - whose state transitions are largely self-contained - what's the best way to implement this kind of "multiple simultaneous states"?

(Or please correct me if this is not what "multiple simultaneous states" means)

Answer (score 1):

what exactly you are trying to achieve is not very clear but this might help.
[Multiple-Named-Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

### OR

you can also manage states like:

```
$stateProvider.state("a", {
        url: "/a",    
        title: "PartA",
        templateUrl: "partA.html",
        controller: "aCtrl"
      }).state("a.list", {
        url: "/list/:id",    
        title: "PartA-List",
        views: {
          "list": {
            templateUrl: "partA.list.html"
          }
        }      
      }).state("a.list.detail", {
        url: "/detail/:rowId",
        title: "PartA-Detail",
        views: {
          "detail": {
            templateUrl: "partA.detail.html"
          }
        }
     });
```

a.html

```
<div ui-view="list"></div>
```

partA.list.html

```
<div ui-view="detail"></div>
```

Comment: He wants to have two parts of his application track their states in an unsynced manner.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible with ui-router.

However the topic has been breached in various incarnations.

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/95
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/160